# How to add headers in below redirected URL in Struts 1.x?

Tags: java, struts

how to add headers in below redirected url in strurts 1.x?

```
ActionRedirect redirect = new ActionRedirect(mapping.findForward(forwardPage));
        redirect.addParameter("method", forwardPage);

        redirect.addParameter("username", "user");
        redirect.addParameter("password", "PWD");
        redirect.addParameter("forwardPage", "success");

    return redirect;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add headers with the `response` object. For example

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Comment: Thanks roman for your concern. How can I test this? I just redirect to my own Servlet and get this header I still get null.                             ActionRedirect redirect = new ActionRedirect(mapping.findForward(SUCCESSUSER));

      response.setHeader("Auth", "My Key")''
      redirect.addParameter("response_type", "code");
      redirect.addParameter("client_id", "testclient");
      redirect.addParameter("scope", "paytm");
      redirect.addParameter("redirect_uri", "some url");

      return redirect;

Comment: Inside Servlet code :- request.getHeader("Auth") got null.

Comment: It's response header.